# Java app to display figurate numbers doesn't work

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I wanted to create an app to display figurate numbers to some given value (x) according to this equation:
(n+d-2)!*((p-2)(n-1)+d))/d!/(n-1)! = x
where either d and p are given by the user. At first I did it with "int", but it displayed very litte numbers. Then I changed it to "long", but it still displayed not as much numbers as I wanted. So I decided I should use "BigInteger". Unfortunately, with BigInteger, the app doesn't work at all. It gets stuck, but it works, what I see in task manager (processor is loaded). Here is the code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger W = BigInteger.valueOf(in.nextLong());
        BigInteger K = BigInteger.valueOf(in.nextLong());
        long x = in.nextLong();     
        BigInteger X = BigInteger.valueOf(x);

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            BigInteger I = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
            BigInteger J = BigInteger.ZERO;

            int poronanie = factorial(J.add(W).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).multiply((K.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).multiply(J.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(W)).compareTo(I.multiply(factorial(W)).multiply(factorial(J.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))));

            while (poronanie == -1){
                J = J.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                poronanie = factorial(J.add(W).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).multiply((K.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).multiply(J.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(W)).compareTo(I.multiply(factorial(W)).multiply(factorial(J.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))));
            }

            if (poronanie == 0){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

        while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            result = result.multiply(n);
            n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Do You have any idea, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Converting `long` to `BigInteger` won't work, as the value was previously `long`, and anything that `long` can't contain is lost

Comment: @OverCoder I know, I said metaphorically, that I changed long to BigInteger. You have the whole code in my post and I think it should work, but does not.

Comment: try to use `BigDecimal` @Leftismer

Comment: @Leftismer `long x = 1e14; // X now has 1e14`, `int y = x; // y won't contain 1e14, it will overflow`, `long z = y; // z will still not have 1e14, but what y has now`. `in.nextLong()` gets a `Long` no matter where you store that

Comment: @Kaushal28 doesn't work as well.